# Upload image file with specified name using laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to store the image file with the `id` as a name .

So I tried the following code :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
'casting_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
      ]);
     if ($validator->passes()) {
              $request->casting_photo->storeAs(public_path('castingimages'),$request->Casting()->id.'.'.$request->casting_photo->extension() );
             $data = ['casting_photo' =>$request->casting_photo];
       
       Casting::create($data);

        return response()->json(["status" => "success", "message" => "Success! post created."]);
             
      }
              return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "message" => "Alert! post not created"]);
    }
```

But it gives me the `500 (Internal Server Error)`

**EDIT**

```
 if ($validator->passes()) {
      $input['casting_photo'] = $request->Casting()->id .'.'.$request->casting_photo->extension();
        $request->casting_photo->storeAs(public_path('castingimages'),$request->Casting()->id.'.'.$request->casting_photo->extension() );
         $data = ['casting_name' => $request->casting_name,
         'casting_cin' => $request->casting_cin,
         'casting_email' => $request->casting_email,
         'casting_phone' => $request->casting_phone,
          'casting_age' => $request->casting_age,
         'casting_sexe' => $request->casting_sexe,
         'casting_city' => $request->casting_city,
         'casting_address' => $request->casting_address,  
         'casting_photo'=> $input['casting_photo'] ];
   
   Casting::create($data);


    return response()->json(["status" => "success", "message" => "Success! post created."]);
         
   
  }
          return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "message" => "Alert! post not created"]);
```

I tried that and the same error occurs.

**EDIT2**

```
$fileName = $request->get('id') . '.' . $request->file('casting_photo')->extension();        
       $request->file('casting_photo')->storeAs('castingimages', $fileName);
```

But in databse I finf the image stored with just the extension like `.png`

**EDIT3**

```
<form id="castingform" method="post" action="castings"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
       
                     {{ csrf_field() }}

                             <input type="hidden" name="id" /> 
                              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                  <label for="casting_name">Nom</label>
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_name" name="casting_name" placeholder="Nom" >
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_name') }}</span>
                               </div>
                                 <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                       <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="custom-file">
                                    
                                        <input type="file" name="casting_photo" class="custom-file-input" id="casting_photo">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                      <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_photo') }}</span>
                                     </div>
                                       <label class="custom-file-label" for="casting_photo">Choose file</label>

                                    </div>

                                 </div>

                                  <button type="submit" id="createBtn" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
                                  
          </form>
```

Comment: dd($request->all()) show what you get in request

Comment: I get 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: remove all code isnide validation passes and dd($request->all())

Comment: You are adding casting_photo as a file to your data, instead you need to add the file name only

Comment: @Znar please check my EDIT

Comment: @user14053977.it should be   $request->casting_photo->storeAs(public_path('castingimages'),$request->id.'.'.$request->casting_photo->extension() );

Comment: did you set your APP_DEBUG to false in the .env, i can't understand why it's giving 500 server error with no details

Comment: please check John answer below on how to get the id

Comment: I tried it but the same error occurs

Comment: so better dd($request->all());

Comment: @JohnLobo,please check my EIDT2

Comment: because request id is null so.show form blade

Comment: @Znar , please check my EIDT2

Comment: do you id input in your form

Comment: No I don't have it

Comment: then which which id need to add .is it db table id

Comment: I don't wanna show the id in my form , how can I add it ?

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="{{your id}}" />

Comment: what shouls I putting inside the {{}} ?

Comment: its id which you want to add in image

Comment: like thet  <input type="hidden"  value="{{id}}" name="id" />

Comment: It still gives .extention

Comment: show your blade templat code

Comment: chem  my blade tempate

Comment: @user14053977 check my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233088/discussion-between-user14053977-and-john-lobo).

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing unknown id from request

```
 $input['casting_photo'] = $request->Casting()->id .'.'.$request->casting_photo->extension();
```

it should be

```
  $request->casting_photo->storeAs(public_path('castingimages'),$request->id.'.'.$request->casting_photo->extension() );
```

**Updated**

```
        $request->casting_photo->storeAs(public_path('castingimages'),$request->Casting()->id.'.'.$request->casting_photo->extension() );
         
         $data = ['casting_name' => $request->casting_name,
         'casting_cin' => $request->casting_cin,
         'casting_email' => $request->casting_email,
         'casting_phone' => $request->casting_phone,
          'casting_age' => $request->casting_age,
         'casting_sexe' => $request->casting_sexe,
         'casting_city' => $request->casting_city,
         'casting_address' => $request->casting_address,  
         
   
        $casting=Casting::create($data);
        $casting->casting_photo=$casting->id.'.'.$request->casting_photo->extension() );
        $casting->save();
```